# Smart Watch Moto 360 v1 returns Gyroscope values even though it doesn't exist?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, gyroscope

I've been plotting the Gyroscope values and it seems to be working perfectly as only the angular velocity values are returned but I recently opened up its specs where it says that the watch only contains an accelerometer and a heart-rate sensor. If the Gyroscope doesn't exist, how am I getting the values?

This is how I'm using the gyroscope in the app:

```
    sensorManager = (SensorManagergetSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
```

Specs:
http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_360_(1st_gen)-7682.php

Answer (score 0):

Per iFixit teardown: https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Motorola+Moto+360+Teardown/28891

> Step 16: On the flipside: an InvenSense MPU-6051 Six-Axis (Gyro + Accelerometer)
>                MEMS Motion Tracking Device

So there does appear to be a Gyroscope in the Moto 360 v1.